# WIX MSI version 3 > version 4 - Duplicated item in the list of Program installed

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix4

I used HeatWave to migrate the WIX template from version 3 to version 4. If I want to install the MSI on top of an old installation that used version 3 of the WIX MSI template, The file did get updated correctly however, I get a duplicated entrance in the list of "Programs and Features" in the Control Panel in Windows 11.

The UpgradeCode is the same as for the old MSI installation. I added :

```
<Upgrade Id="same-id-as-UpgradeCode">
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="1.0.0" Maximum="reference-to-actual-version" Property="PREVIOUSFOUND" IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="no" />
</Upgrade>
```

That change did not change the outcome.
The program version is higher and some of the file being updated have higher version and get replaced, no problem on this side. I already had the entrance :

```
<MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize" DowngradeErrorMessage="message as text" />
```

I look through the log file while running the new MSI and, obviously the part were file get removed is missing, compared to a simple installation.

I went through the schema of the documentation from WIX and I looked through the example of a new project from the HeatWave basic bundle and documentation.

I am out of ideas on how to find, why the version 4, does not pick up on the UpgradeCode and remove the MSI package. I have try to repeat the test with the older version of MSI WIX version 3 of the software, the new one with version 4 and the new one with version 3. It is always the same result (old.msi v3 > new.msi v3 (success), v3 > v4 (duplicate)).

*The migration of the template removed the Product key and instead added Package in its place, the Id=* in Product is not present anymore but as pointed in the log of the migration this is ok*

There are some errors in the logs file, they look related to an "SQL" request. The most verbose one is as follow :

> MSI (s) (34:08) [17:41:05:031]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error  MSI (s)
> (34:08) [17:41:05:031]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message`
> FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2911  DEBUG: Error 2911:  Could not
> remove the folder C:\Config.Msi. The installer has encountered an
> unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem
> with this package. The error code is 2911. The arguments are:
> C:\Config.Msi, ,

The main difference in the log between the successful upgrade and the failure is as follow; Upgrade :

> Action 17:56:26: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related
> applications Found application: [1] Action start 17:56:26:
> FindRelatedProducts. FindRelatedProducts:  MSI (c) (6C:90)
> [17:56:26:090]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED property.
> Its value is '{887DFE8D-6464-4D97-BED3-70E80F38FF67}'. MSI (c) (6C:90)
> [17:56:26:090]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MIGRATE property. Its value is
> '{887DFE8D-6464-4D97-BED3-70E80F38FF67}'.

The failure :

> Action 17:39:40: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related
> applications Found application: [1] Action start 17:39:40:
> FindRelatedProducts. MSI (c) (50:A4) [17:39:40:465]:
> FindRelatedProducts: current install is per-machine.  Related install
> for product '{887DFE8D-6464-4D97-BED3-70E80F38FF67}' is per-user.
> Skipping... MSI (c) (50:A4) [17:39:40:465]: FindRelatedProducts:
> current install is per-machine.  Related install for product
> '{887DFE8D-6464-4D97-BED3-70E80F38FF67}' is per-user.  Skipping...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually found the problem:

```
FindRelatedProducts: current install is per-machine. Related install for product '{887DFE8D-6464-4D97-BED3-70E80F38FF67}' is per-user. Skipping...
```

Your new package is per-machine, but your old MSI is per-user. The Windows Installer will not upgrade across install scopes.

Comment: @Dev1n.101 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/major-upgrades  look for the purple Note box for the explanation.

Comment: I tried to add Package/Scope="perUser" and "perUserOrMachine". In both case, the MSI ask for admin elevation. However, in the case of this two options I get this error message "The installer has insufficient privileges to access this directory: C\Program Files (x86)\Project. The installation cannot continue. Log on as administrator or contact your system administrator." In the logs, the process is clearly elevated with success. I tried "PerMachine" option and the result is the same as the initial issue; duplicate appear in list. Is it possible to do PerUser and require elevation as in WIX v.3?

Comment: I have accepted your answer as the solution, however, in reality it does not solve the problem. It rather highlight why this problem exist but not how to solve it. It seems that between the version 3 and version 4 there an important different in the type of scope. Obviously when the MSI was created (probably 10 years ago) the scope was not mentioned, but the files being modifying being in Program Files, it is now flag as a PerMachine. I will look if I can open an issue on the WIX side.